# SQL Query not to get duplicate

Tags: sql-server

I have a main table1 that has duplicate FA_PERIOD 3.  Table 1 is a CTE output.  I will need to join to table 2 to table 1 on field OBJECT_ID, FA_YEAR and FA_PERIOD, but the duplicate field in Table 1 will cause an issue due to the duplicate.  I'm trying to marry the two tables together to show the CTRY runtot and the Running Total field together in one table.  Appreciate any help.

```
Table 1.
OBJECT_ID, AMOUNT, FA_YEAR, FA_PERIOD, CTRY runtot
22203   259 2015    5      $257.00
22203   259 2015    6      $514.00
22203   259 2015    7      $771.00
22203   259 2015    8    $1,028.00
22203   259 2015    9    $1,285.00
22203   259 2015    10   $1,542.00
22203   259 2015    11   $1,799.00
22203   259 2015    12   $2,056.00
22203   259 2016    1    $2,313.00
22203   259 2016    2    $2,570.00
22203   259 2016    3    $2,827.00
22203   -2825   2016    3         $.00
22203   2825    2016    3    $2,827.00
22203   259 2016    4    $3,084.00


Table 2.
OBJECT_ID,FA_YEAR,FA_PERIOD,RunningTOTAL
    22203   2016    1      $257.00
    22203   2016    2      $514.00
    22203   2016    3      $771.00
    22203   2016    4    $1,028.00
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. Can you please try to explain what you need. Also, if you could post your desired output from the sample data that would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to get the running total at *Object_Id, FA_Year, FA_Period* level. When you do grouping, the duplicates are eliminated.

I have put sample code below to test out your scenario.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
([OBJECT_ID] int, AMOUNT int, FA_YEAR int, FA_PERIOD int, CTRY_runtot money)
insert into #Table1
values
(22203,   259, 2015,    5,      '$257.00'),
(22203,   259, 2015,    6 ,     '$514.00'),
(22203,   259, 2015,    7 ,     '$771.00'),
(22203,   259, 2015,    8 ,   '$1,028.00'),
(22203,   259, 2015,    9 ,   '$1,285.00'),
(22203,   259, 2015,    10,   '$1,542.00'),
(22203,   259, 2015,    11,   '$1,799.00'),
(22203,   259, 2015,    12,   '$2,056.00'),
(22203,   259, 2016,    1 ,   '$2,313.00'),
(22203,   259, 2016,    2 ,   '$2,570.00'),
(22203,   259, 2016,    3 ,   '$2,827.00'),
(22203,   2825,    2016,    3,    '$2,827.00'),
(22203,   -2825,   2016,    3,        '$.00');
CREATE TABLE #Table2
([OBJECT_ID] int, FA_YEAR int, FA_PERIOD int, runningtotal money)
insert into #Table2
values
    (22203,   2016,    1,      '$257.00'),
    (22203,   2016,    2,      '$514.00'),
    (22203,   2016,    3,      '$771.00'),
    (22203,   2016,    4,    '$1,028.00');


SELECT t1.[OBJECT_ID]
       ,t1.FA_YEAR    
       ,t1.FA_PERIOD  
       ,sum(t1.CTRY_runtot) as CTRY_runtot
       ,SUM(t2.runningtotal) as runningtotal
from #Table1 t1
JOIN #Table2 t2
ON  t1.[OBJECT_ID] =   t2.[OBJECT_ID]
AND t1.FA_YEAR     = t2.FA_YEAR
AND t1.FA_PERIOD   = t2.FA_PERIOD
GROUP BY 
t1.[OBJECT_ID]
       ,t1.FA_YEAR    
       ,t1.FA_PERIOD
```

**EDIT**

Based on comments on the expected resultset, updating the query.

```
SELECT [OBJECT_ID]
       ,FA_YEAR    
       ,FA_PERIOD  
       ,CTRY_runtot
       ,CASE WHEN rnk=1 THEN CAST(runningtotal as VARCHAR(10)) ELSE ''  END as RunningTotal
FROM 
(SELECT t1.[OBJECT_ID]
       ,t1.FA_YEAR    
       ,t1.FA_PERIOD  
       ,t1.CTRY_runtot
       ,t2.runningtotal
       ,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY t1.[OBJECT_ID]
       ,t1.FA_YEAR    
       ,t1.FA_PERIOD ORDER BY t2.runningtotal) as rnk
       from #Table1 t1
JOIN #Table2 t2
ON  t1.[OBJECT_ID] =   t2.[OBJECT_ID]
AND t1.FA_YEAR     = t2.FA_YEAR
AND t1.FA_PERIOD   = t2.FA_PERIOD
       )as t
```

Comment: Thank you Venkataraman, but I do not want the values to change.  I want to maintain the values CTRY_runtot and running totals.  The dollars amounts are accurate and I need to maintain those values when I tie the two tables together.

Comment: Do you only want records where amount = 259 in table 1? This would remove the duplicates.

Comment: I need to have all amounts.

Comment: Im confused then...what is the duplicate you are trying to get rid of.

Comment: If I join table 1 to table 2 on Object ID, FA_YEAR and FA_PERIOD to pull in one CTRY_runtot and running total wouldn't that cause duplicate since table 1 has 3 FA_PERIODS?

Comment: Yes runningtotal would appear 3 times but you just said thats what you wanted...do you want to aggregate ctry tot perhaps?

Comment: Please just post a desired output

Comment: This is what I'm getting when I join by OBJECT_ID, FA_YEAR AND FA_PERIOD.

Comment: current output
OBJECTID,FA_YEAR,FA_MONTH, curtot_amount,  runningtotals
22203 2016 1  $2,313.00    $257.00
22203 2016 2  $2,570.00    $514.00
22203 2016 3  $2,827.00    $771.00
22203 2016 3       $.00    $771.00
22203 2016 3  $2,827.00    $771.00
22203 2016 4  $3,084.00  $1,028.00

Desired output
OBJECTID,FA_YEAR,FA_MONTH,curtot_amount,runningtotals
22203 2016 1  $2,313.00    $257.00
22203 2016 2  $2,570.00    $514.00
22203 2016 3  $2,827.00    $771.00
22203 2016 3       $.00   
22203 2016 3  $2,827.00    
22203 2016 4  $3,084.00  $1,028.00

Comment: I believe I have an idea of how to resolve this but need some assistance. I'm using a partition by to only grab the 2016 data but can't get the partition to work below is the query.

Comment: select 
OBJECT_ID,
FA_YEAR,
YTD_TOTAL,
ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY OBJECT_ID ORDER BY FA_YEAR desc) rw
from YTD_DEPRECIATION

Comment: OBJECT_ID,FA_YEAR,YTD_TOTAL,RW
22208 2016    $773.00 1
22208 2016    $513.00 2
22208 2016    $255.00 3
22208 2016  $1,036.00 4
22208 2015  $1,225.00 5
22208 2015  $1,798.00 6
22208 2015  $2,052.00 7
22208 2015  $1,029.00 8
22208 2015    $772.00 9
22208 2015    $515.00 10
22208 2015    $252.00 11
22208 2015  $1,545.00 12

Comment: I only want to grab the latest year data so I only want to select 2016 data. I believe the partition is the way to go.  I just need to only select 2016 so rank 2016 all 1 and 2015 all 2.

Comment: Just apply filter *WHERE FA_YEAR = 2016" *. The above query will work in PL/SQL also.